# Why the exterior of PC towers and monitors used to be white in the 90's and now is black?

Tags: history, crt-monitor, case

White got dirty pretty quick. Why would they chose that color?
And why MAC still keep it but other manufacturers do not.

Comment: Changing fashions, is basically all there is to this, I believe. And while the majority of computers of any given era may have had a single colour, there have always been dissenters (eg Sinclair machines were black from the beginning of the 80s until after Amstrad bought them; and the less said about the iMac the better...).

Comment: This isn't a brilliant question... I'm voting to close as Primarily Opinion Based because it's unlikely that we'll ever know the real answer; humans are just that complicated when it comes to fashion. Otherwise, it'd probably fall under "Off-topic".

Comment: The all black NeXT Cube was released in 1990. Most PC design "fashion" can be traced to Steve Jobs, with a 5 to 10 year lag.

Comment: One reason for not using white is that bromine fire retardant would cause severe yellowing with age.

Comment: "Follow the leader."  It's largely 3 eras, with IBM's dominance in the middle.  Pre-IBM, there was a huge variety of colors in the microcomputer market.  Then when the IBM PC was introduced, many tried to copy various aspects of it -- not just the color but also size, shape, ports, even chips -- hoping to ride the wave of IBM's success.  Hence the nickname "beige box".  By the late 1990s, the yellowing effect @amI noted made people rethink lightly-colored cases.  Apple's resurgence in the 2000s made it the new target for others to follow.

Comment: From the answer we can see it is not an opinion-based question so I do not understand why it is on hold

Comment: I am not sure it's opinion based. If you bother to ask a plastics manufacturer they'll tell you one reason straight off. In the 1990s you needed a much better quality (ie very expensive) mould to make a nice shiny black case. A beige plastic case covers many moulding sins.

Comment: This question could be salvaged by rewording it to ask about the economic, technical and fashion trends that drove the colouring and appearance of computer cases over time.